# Jquery Deferred. Multiple ajax calls. deferred vs async false

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, deferred

I've got the following.

```
var lookupInit = function () {            
        http.get('api/employmenttype', null, false)
            .done(function (response) {
                console.log('loaded: employmenttype');
                vm.lookups.allEmploymentTypes(response);
            });    
        http.get('api/actionlist', null, false)
            .done(function (response) {
                console.log('loaded: actionlist');
                vm.lookups.allActionListOptions(response);
            });    
        http.get('api/company', null, false)
            .done(function (response) {
                console.log('loaded: company');
                vm.lookups.allCompanies(response);
            });    

        //... x 5 more
        return true;
    };



// somewhere else
  if (lookupInit(id)) {
        vm.userInfo.BusinessUnitID('0');
        vm.userInfo.BuildingCode('0');

          if (id === undefined) {
                console.log('api/adimport: latest');
                http.json('api/adimport', { by: "latest" }, false).done(viewInit);
          }
          else if (id !== undefined) {
                console.log('api/adimport: transaction');
                http.json('api/adimport', { by: "transaction", TransactionId: id }, false).done(viewInit);
          }
  } else {
      console.log('User info init failed!');
  }
```

The following "http.get('api/employmenttype', null, **false**)" means i set async to false.
I'm aware that this is probably inefficient. And i'd like to have all the calls load simultaneously.
The only problem is if i don't have them set to async false, the second part of my code might execute before the dropdowns are populated.

I've tried a couple of attempts with Jquery Deferreds, but they have resulted in what i can only describe as an abortion.

The only thing i'm looking to achieve is that the lookup calls finish before the adimport/second part of my code, in any order.... But having each call wait for the one before it to finish EG: async, seems like the only solution I'm capable of implementing decently ATM.

**Would this be an appropriate place for deferred function, and could anyone  point me into a direction where i could figure out how to implement it correctly, as I've never done this before?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when) to combine multiple promises to one that resolves when all of them have been fulfilled. If I got you correctly, you want

```
function lookupInit() {            
    return $.when(
        http.get('api/employmenttype').done(function (response) {
            console.log('loaded: employmenttype');
            vm.lookups.allEmploymentTypes(response);
        }),
        http.get('api/actionlist').done(function (response) {
            console.log('loaded: actionlist');
            vm.lookups.allActionListOptions(response);
        }),
        http.get('api/company').done(function (response) {
            console.log('loaded: company');
            vm.lookups.allCompanies(response);
        }),
        // … some more
    );
}
```

Then somewhere else

```
lookupInit(id).then(function(/* all responses if you needed them */) {
    vm.userInfo.BusinessUnitID('0');
    vm.userInfo.BuildingCode('0');

    if (id === undefined) {
         console.log('api/adimport: latest');
         return http.json('api/adimport', {by:"latest"})
    } else {
         console.log('api/adimport: transaction');
         return http.json('api/adimport', {by:"transaction", TransactionId:id});
    }
}, function(err) {
    console.log('User info init failed!');
}).done(viewInit);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Jquery API I've found this about resolving multiple deferreds:

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php")).done(function(a1, a2){
    /* a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the
        page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively.
        each argument is an array with the following
        structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ] */
    var data = a1[0] + a2[0]; /* a1[0] = "Whip", a2[0] = " It" */
    if ( /Whip It/.test(data) ) {
        alert("We got what we came for!");
    }
});
```

Using this with your code:

```
var defer = $.when(
    $.get('api/employmenttype'),
    $.get('api/actionlist'),
    $.get('api/company'),
    // ... 5 more
);

defer.done(function (arg1, arg2, arg3 /*, ... 5 more*/) {
    vm.lookups.allEmploymentTypes(arg1[0]);
    vm.lookups.allEmploymentTypes(arg2[0]);
    vm.lookups.allEmploymentTypes(arg3[0]);
    // .. 5 more

    vm.userInfo.BusinessUnitID('0');
    vm.userInfo.BuildingCode('0');

    if (id === undefined) {
        console.log('api/adimport: latest');
        http.json('api/adimport', { by: "latest" }, false).done(viewInit);
    } else if (id !== undefined) {
        console.log('api/adimport: transaction');
        http.json('api/adimport', { by: "transaction", TransactionId: id }, false).done(viewInit);
    }
});
```

You can use the defer of the $.when() inside an other $.when(), so if the json calls are not dependant on the first calls you can add them in a an onther defer.